# maniuplation of data frame column with sum

Tags: r, dataframe

Let us say that I have a column a, I want to crate a new column let’s call it c. In column c I want to have values of ‘a’ divided by two plus value of previous observation (t-1). What is the best practice approach to achieve that? Sample data:

```
Input <- ("
      nuimber       a   c 
      1      0         0         
      2      2         2            
      3      3         3         
      ")
data <- read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)
```

Thus i want to have each value in a divided by two plus value of c in (t-1)

Expected output

```
      nuimber       a   c 
      1      0         0         
      2      2         2/2+0            
      3      3         3/2+1
```

Comment: You may need `library(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate(c = a/2 + lag(a))` or in `base R`, `df1$c <- df1$a/2 + c(NA, df1$a[-nrow(df1$a))`

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: Here, in the sample, `c` is the same as 'a'.  Is that expected column?

Comment: Yes 'c' is a copy of 'a' which will be modified.

Comment: Try the code I commented above and check if that is your expected (change 'df1' by 'data'

Comment: But mutate will create a new column what if i want to overwrite 'c'?

Comment: You are overwriting it `data %>% mutate(c = a/2 + lag(a, default = 0))`

Comment: Will it work with `lag(c)`? That is what I am looking for

Comment: Yes, it would work as well.  Not clear about the expected as both 'a' and 'c' are the same

Comment: Can you update with expected output

Comment: Did it already so you can have a look